Excel, sum of X number of cells under current cell
I'm trying to calculate the sum of X (2) cells under the current cell. In this example, I want A1 to be the sum of X cells under the current cell (A1); A1 = A2 + A3; A1 = 4 + 7; A1 = 11.

In this other example, I want A1 to be the sum of X (3) cells under current cell (A1); A1 = A2 + A3 + A4; A1 = 4 + 7 + 8; A1 = 19.

To simplify this, I' have created the examples with A1, but I would like to use the formula on any cell and add the value of X cells under the current cell.
I've tried with OFFSET without success.
=SUM(OFFSET(A1:A10,1,0,C1,1))

It works but I would like to change A1:A10 for a more generic version.
Any advice? Thanks

I think this is what you had in mind:
=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),1,0,C1,1))

or "old style":
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,ROW()+1):INDEX(A:A,ROW()+C1))

or if you really hate anyone who has to maintain it in future:
=LET(
    α, ROW(),
    β, LAMBDA(χ, ROW() + χ),
    γ, LAMBDA(ν, SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(A:A, α), 1, 0, ν, 1))),
    δ, γ(C1),
    δ
)



You could try using the following as well:


=SUM(TAKE(A2:A6,C1))


Suggesting to avoid the use volatile functions like OFFSET() this is because volatile functions makes the working functionality of excel slow as well it will keep on recalculating whenever there is a change in any open workbook.

Or Using INDEX():
=SUM(INDEX(A2:A6,ROW(ZZ1:INDEX(Z:Z,C1))))


Or,
=SUM(CHOOSEROWS(A2:A6,SEQUENCE(C1)))



Hello this can be done in multiple ways, i m using Excel 2021:

using offset as you already have tried:
=SUM(OFFSET(A2,0,0,C1,1))

using index with row and indirect functions:
=SUM(INDEX(A2:A6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C1))))

index and sequence - formula in A1:
=SUM(INDEX(A2:A6,SEQUENCE(C1)))



Hope it helps.
